# How to handle App.XAML events in Main.cs?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to know how I handle events that I set in my App.XAML file in a standard WPF configuration. I have a button in my App.XAML file and I would like to add an event handler which is located in my Main.CS file.

Example code:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"

<Button Click="Myhandler" />
```

Even though App.CS and Main.CS both share the same namespace I get an error saying that my handler does not exist. How can I set the context in the right way?

Comment: You can't do that. Either move the button to Main.xaml OR bind Command DP to some ICommand in ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the class of your App.xaml is `MyApp.App`:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
   ...
>
```

`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"` is just like adding a `using local = MyApp;` line to the beginning of a c# code.

You have to create your event handlers in MyApp.App. but if you're concerned about the **Right** way to do it you should use Commands instead of event handlers.